# Does speed of tar.gz file listing depend on tar size?

Tags: tar

I am using the tf function to list the contents of a tar.gz file.  It is pretty large ~1 GB.  There are around 1000 files organized in a year/month/day file structure.

The listing operation takes quit a bit of time.  Seems like a listing should be fast.  Can anyone enlighten me on the internals?

Thanks -

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28file_format%29#Format_details), for example, to verify that each file inside the tar is preceed by a header. To verify all files inside the tar, is necessary to read the whole tar.

There's no "index" in the beggining of the tar to indicate it's contents.

Answer (score 2):

Tar has simple file structure. If you want list  them, you must parse all file.
If you want find one file, you can stop process. But must be sure archive has only one file version. This is typical on packed archives because adding on that is unsupported.
for example you can do like this:

```
tar tvzf somefile.gz|grep for find something|\
while read file; do foundfile="$file"; last; done
```

at this loop will break and do not read everything, but only from start to file position.

If you must do something more with list, save it to any temporary file. you can gzip this file for place saving if it is needed:

```
tar tvzf somefile.gz|gzip >temporary_filelist.gz
```